# Steps to Import a project on Android Studio (Gradle Based)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Im trying to work in Android Studio Project that was created on another machine.

This is a gradle based project but Android Studio do not recognize it as gradle based.

by the way I cannot build it because it says AndroidManifest.xml it doesnt exist.

I already tried to run the Google maps v1, api v2, Anywall on parse.

any of this projects are working for me.

I already have set up the JAVA_HOME and GRADLE_HOME. 
Also I have known that I need to add this variables into the Path on the Environment Variables.

Thank you guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried File > Import Project .. Than follow the instructions, accepting everything usually. Than A.S. will probably ask you to install missing stuff like SDKs if they are not already installed in you A.S. version. 
And also, check your build.gradle(Module: app) -> buildTypes

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried the same code in different ways,

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}